# Dim Statement and Calling a Cell in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Visual Basic Code in a spreadsheet.  It is calling specific cells in the spreadsheet.  I don't understand why I can call Cells A3:A5 with the below code, but not A21:A23.  I've only put as an example the call to A21.

The error tells me:

Type Mismatch

```
Sub WriteDataToTsin1(FileIn)
Dim A21 As Double
Dim A4 As Single
Dim A5 As Single
'Dim A6 As Single

A21 = Cells(22, 1)
A4 = Cells(4, 1)
A5 = Cells(5, 1)
'A6 = Cells(36, 1)

Open FileIn For Output As #1
Write #1, A21, A4, A5

Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: You have the variable `A21` declared as a `Double`. What's in cell A21?

Comment: @rick-hart: if cell A21 in the worksheet isn't numeric, you will get that error ... better to just declare your variables as strings, then it won't matter

Comment: @OurManinBananas Declaring them as `String` will still fail if the cells contain errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  A buddy that codes discussed that formatting is an issue.  He suggested I use the statement:

Comment: Sorry, hit the return.  Dim A21  which will default to Variant.  That has worked fine so far without issues.